# set Progress bar Based on Controller Method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Email Send project in which controller side there is one method which is sending emails to 2000 client. So i want to get count of email proceed , and total number of email id from controller to view and update the progress bar. how can i do this?  count of both are not fix both will be decided after submission of form.

Is it possible by sending multiple Ajax request After submission of form?

**Controller Method**

`long totalcount = 0;`
  `long CCount = 0;`

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SendMail(SendMailRequest sm) 
  { 
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          dt = GetAllEmailIds();
          totalCount = dt.rows.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               client.send();
               Count++;
            }
  } 



 [HttpGet]
        public string GetCount()
        {
            string message = "";
            message = "completed " + CCount + " out of  " + totalcount + "";
            return message;
        }
```

in View After Form Submission

```
  updatevalue();

        function updatevalue() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Email/GetCount',
                type: "GET",     
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
            setTimeout(updatevalue(), 1000);
        };
```

Comment: No I don't Know About SingalR I am novice to  ASP.NET

Comment: check this sample - http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Its a different schenario:

But the solution you may use is:

set a global private variable:

```
private int _mailSent;
```

Increase this within the post action method.

Create another action which returns the value for that variable asynchronously, make use of continues call to that method and set the progress bar.

Comment: Yes but how to create that action which returns variable asynchronously and how to call it continuesly that method right now i am doing it by repeat ajax call but is is not working

Comment: you can create action as usual like public ActionResult GetMailSent(){ return Json(new {_mailSent});} make sure put a httppost there. and you can create a request method in jquery in view

Comment: see the above code i have edited doing the same thing

Comment: first change it to HttpPost then return a json object having a string with counts

Comment: How to call from View?? After Submit Form??

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Startmailing()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            { _count++;
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCount()
        {
            return Json(new {Messaage = $"Mail sent={_count}"});
        }

Comment: function startMailing(){$.ajax({url:'@Url.Action("Startmailing", "Home")',type:"POST",success:function(a){}})}function showCount(){$.ajax({url:'@Url.Action("GetCount", "Home")',type:"POST",success:function(a){console.log(a)}}),setTimeout(showCount(),1e3)}$(document).ready(function(){startMailing(),showCount()});

Comment: if didnt receive the count or count doesnt increase during mail sending you can save it into db and retrieve it from db and return as same.  Make sure to check as Answer if solved

Comment: its working here, May be you have been missing something anywhere.

Comment: I tried both save into database and global variable but the problem is count is not increasing because it c is calling only  **getcount()**  method method again and again.. **Startmailing()** is no executing  do you have any idea? how to execute both method simultaneously.. so that count can increase..

Comment: You have to call StartMailing Method First after that getCount should be execute, StartMailing process the mailing, increment and storing incremented value in DB

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {  
      
        startMailing();  
        showCount();  
    }); doing same as you described above

Comment: saving in database worked !! so Useful  comment vote but still looking for another solution......